# AJAX only returning first character of variable

Tags: php, ajax

The output from the following script is `1h`, whereas I would expect it to be `1hello`.

```
var id = "1";
var shop_name = "hello";
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.domain.com/includes/follow.php",
    data: {shop_name: shop_name, id: id},
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

*follow.php*

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$shop_name = $_POST['shop_name'];

echo $id['id'];
echo $shop_name['shop_name'];

?>
```

Comment: You're basically doing `echo $_POST['id']['id']`? I'm surprised that doesn't throw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning them to variables as strings not to another associative array with indexes.  Just use:

```
echo $id;
echo $shop_name;
```

When you do this:

```
echo $id['id'];
echo $shop_name['shop_name'];
```

Since they are strings, PHP echos the `[0]` index of the string which is `1` for `$id` and `h` for `$shop_name`.

If you use:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

You would see:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in follow.php on line 5
1
Warning: Illegal string offset 'shop_name' in follow.php on line 6
h
```